# Regex to match vowels in order a-e-i-o-u

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to match patterns where the `vowels` are in order, shouldn't repeat and can be separated by `non-vowels`.

Currently I am just testing it with `a` and `e`. However, I am not getting the output I expect.

```
grep 'a[^aeiou]*e[^aeiou]*'
```

So for example `ae`, `abeb`, `abbbbbbeb` should all match.

However, `aeeb` shouldn't match.

With my regex, why is this matching?

I would have thought the the first `e` in `aeeb` would match the `e` in `a[^aeiou]*e[^aeiou]*` and the rest of the regex would fail?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What about `y` and `w`?  Also what is the application for this? (Homework?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a[^aeiou]*e[^aeiou]*` matches the `ae` in `aeeb`.

If you want to make sure the line `aeeb` doesn't match, you have to anchor the regex:

```
^a[^aeiou]*e[^aeiou]*$
```

Comment: If non-vowels can also be leading characters, he may want another `[^aeiou]*` in the front.  I assume this is all case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Use the beginning of string `^` and end of string `$` anchors.

```
#!/bin/sh
STRING=$( cat <<EOF
ae
abeb
abbbbbbeb
aeeb
EOF
)
echo "$STRING" | grep '^a[^aeiou]*e[^aeiou]*$'
## ae
## abeb
## abbbbbbeb
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm way too late to this, but for anyone stumbling upon this later, you can simply use:

```
grep -P "a.*e.*i.*o.*u" myfile.txt
```

In plain English, this is an 'a' followed by 0 or more of any other letter, followed by 'e', followed by 0 or more of any other letter and so on.

If you are searching through a dictionary like the ones in /usr/shares/dict/ this will do the same as the other working code snippets. However, it is worth mentioning that this will not match the entire word. It will only match from the first 'a' to the first 'u' (assuming the 'u' is last letter in the matching vowel sequence) leaving out the leading and trailing characters. For example, in 'facetious' only 'etiou' will be matched. If you want to match the whole word, you can modify the regex to this:

```
grep -P ".*a.*e.*i.*o.*u.*" myfile.txt
```

Note the '.*' at the beginning and end.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should also have a non-vowel bracket expression in front to account for words starting with a character other than aeiou since you're allowing it at the end:

```
egrep '^[^aeiou]*a[^aeiou]*e[^aeiou]$'
```